# Ionic ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to find the distance between a location input from the user and a fixed location. I want to use the DistanceMatrix service from google platform, but I keep getting the "google is not defined" error.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AlertController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

declare var google : any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  templateUrl: './checkout.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./checkout.page.scss'],
})
export class CheckoutPage {
  payment = ""
  name  : string  = ""
  phone : string = ""
  address  : string  = ""

  constructor(private alertController : AlertController, private router:Router, private dataService : DataService, private toastController : ToastController) { 



    var to = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("address") as HTMLInputElement)
  }
```

I would also like for the input to autocomplete as the user types.

I have been stuck on this for 3 days now.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you testing this in firefox? Is the behaviour same in all browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this with a little delay, but one way to fix it is as follows:

First you need to install @types/googlemaps :

```
npm install --save @types/googlemaps
```

Then if you are using Angular-cli, add googlemaps to types in src/tsconfig.app.json:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": [
      "googlemaps"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

After that, you probably won't have this problem anymore.

source: https://roufid.com/angular-uncaught-referenceerror-google-not-defined/